# Cómo redireccionar a sub-página luego de ingresar contraseña correcta en 'Password Protected'? - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, redirección

Tengo una página protegida con contraseña utilizando la opción que trae Wordprees 'Password Protected'. Esta página tiene sub-páginas, si se ingresa a una subágina y la página padre tiene contraseña, entonces redirecciona a su página padre para ingresar la contraseña y ver el contenido de cada página.

Lo que necesito ahora es que sólo cuando se ingresa la contraseña correcta en la página padre, debe redireccionar a la primera página hijo.

Lo que he realizado hasta el momento sí hace esa redirección, pero una vez ingresada la contraseña correcta y necesito ver la página padre desde el menú o escribiendo la url, redirecciona nuevamente a la primera página hijo y no puedo ver la página padre, solo necesito que redireccione la primera vez que se ingrese la contraseña.

Hay alguna manera de realizar eso con otra condición? Por favor necesito ayuda !!!

No podría poner la url estática en la redirección porque debe funcionar con cualquier otro grupo de páginas (padre y sub-páginas).

Este es mi código:

```
<?php 
global $post;

// Verifica si es sub-página: 
if (is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {
    $ancestors = $post->ancestors;
    foreach ( $ancestors as $ancestor ) {
        // Si página padre tiene contraseña
        if ( post_password_required( $ancestor ) ) {

            //Redirecciona a su página padre
            $parent_url = get_permalink($post->post_parent);
            header('Location:' . $parent_url);
            exit();
        }
    }
} 

// De lo contrario es página padre:
else {

    if( $post->post_password && !post_password_required($post->post_parent)) {
        
        //Redirecciona a primera pagina hijo
        $pagekids = get_pages("child_of=".$post->ID."&sort_column=menu_order");
        if ($pagekids) {
            if (!get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dont_redirect', true)) {
                $firstchild = $pagekids[0];
                wp_redirect(get_permalink($firstchild->ID));
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Esta pregunta parece ser un duplicado de https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/516787/c%c3%b3mo-redireccionar-una-p%c3%a1gina-hijo-a-su-p%c3%a1gina-padre-wordpress por favor elimina una de las dos preguntas

Comment: Listo, está eliminado!

Comment: @JefferzonBol De hecho no es un duplicado, si es parte de, pero ya logré realizar la mayor parte de lo que necesitaba en la otra pregunta. Ahora ya solo me hace falta lo que describo arriba.